# Using LIMIT with Subqueries in Mysql

Tags: mysql

In my database, a lead can have many tasks and therefore the the tasks table has a taskable_id and taskable_type, where taskable_id is id of lead and taskable_type is "Lead", following the Ruby on Rails polymorphic conventions.

I want to select the first task for all leads whose appointment status is 1. That's it. The result set should be a collection of tasks. This is what I came up with:

```
SELECT 
    `tasks`.* 
FROM 
    `tasks`  
      WHERE `tasks`.`taskable_id` IN (1, 2) 
      AND 
      `tasks`.`taskable_type` = 'Lead' 
      AND 
      `tasks`.`id` 
      IN 
        (
            SELECT  `tasks`.`id` 
            FROM `tasks`  
            WHERE `tasks`.`taskable_id` IN (1, 2) 
            AND 
            `tasks`.`taskable_type` = 'Lead' 
            AND 
            'appointment_status' = 1 
            ORDER BY created_at asc 
            LIMIT 1
        );
```

But this gives error "This version of MySQL doesn't yet support 'LIMIT & IN/ALL/ANY/SOME subquery". Other stackoverflow posts said that for this error, LIMIT must be outside subquery.

Here is example data:

```
mysql> SELECT * FROM tasks;
+----+------+--------+-------------+----------+---------------------+---------------------+-----------+---------------------+---------------------+---------------+-------------+
| id | name | status | description | priority | created_at          | updated_at          | task_type | date_start          | date_due            | taskable_type | taskable_id |
+----+------+--------+-------------+----------+---------------------+---------------------+-----------+---------------------+---------------------+---------------+-------------+
|  1 | NULL |      2 | NULL        |        1 | 2014-09-24 17:53:58 | 2014-09-24 17:53:58 |         1 | 2014-09-25 11:30:00 | 2014-09-25 12:00:00 | Lead          |           1 |
|  2 | NULL |      2 | NULL        |        1 | 2014-09-25 12:45:50 | 2014-09-25 12:45:50 |         1 | 2014-09-25 12:45:00 | 2014-09-25 13:15:00 | Lead          |           2 |

mysql> SELECT id, appointment_status, created_at, updated_at FROM leads;
+----+--------------------+---------------------+---------------------+
| id | appointment_status | created_at          | updated_at          |
+----+--------------------+---------------------+---------------------+
|  1 |                  1 | 2014-09-24 17:45:12 | 2014-09-24 17:53:58 |
|  2 |                  1 | 2014-09-25 12:45:46 | 2014-09-25 12:45:50 |
```

Comment: you second option has no `on` keyword, so your join is invalid. you're basically going `inner join (foo) as t1 (bar) as t2`

Comment: Can you show some sample data?

Comment: @MarcB But I don't see where a on would be useful here. There is no relation between t1 and t2. I am just trying to get the first task for all leads.

Comment: @Mihai Table Tasks: id, taskable_id, taskable_type. Table Leads: id, appointment_status.

Comment: you're also missing a `)` in your second `inner join` query's subselect.

Comment: @DanStayntouch please read [**My Post**](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/271056/2733506) on asking a good question.. we need to see sample data inside the table.. there are also formatting tips and tricks to speed up the process

Answer (score 0):

After some experimentation, it appears I got it working:

```
SELECT 
    tasks.* 
FROM
    tasks 
    INNER JOIN 
        leads
        ON leads.id = tasks.taskable_id AND tasks.taskable_type = "Lead"
WHERE 
    tasks.taskable_id IN (1, 2) 
    AND 
    (
        tasks.id = 
        (
            SELECT tasks.id 
            FROM tasks
            WHERE tasks.taskable_id = leads.id 
            AND
            tasks.taskable_type = "Lead"
            AND 
            appointment_status = 1
            ORDER BY created_at asc
            LIMIT 1
        )
    )
```

Answer (score 0):

An approach without uservars:

```
SELECT
    tasks.*
FROM
    (SELECT taskable_id,
        MIN(t.created_at) created_at
    FROM
        tasks t
    JOIN
        leads l USING (taskable_id)
    WHERE
        taskable_id IN (1,2)
        AND t.taskable_type = 'Lead'
        AND l.appointment_status = 1
    GROUP BY taskable_id
    ) x
JOIN
    tasks
    USING (taskable_id, created_at)
```