# mysql subquery not producing all results

Tags: mysql

I have two tables: contacts and client_profiles. A contact has many client_profiles, where client_profiles has foreign key contact_id:

contacts:

```
mysql> SELECT id,first_name, last_name FROM contacts;
+----+-------------+-----------+
| id | first_name  | last_name |
+----+-------------+-----------+
| 10 | THERESA     | CAMPBELL  |
| 11 | donato      | vig       |
| 12 | fdgfdgf     | gfdgfd    |
| 13 | some random | contact   |
+----+-------------+-----------+
4 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

client_profiles:

```
mysql> SELECT id, contact_id, created_at FROM client_profiles;
+----+------------+---------------------+
| id | contact_id | created_at          |
+----+------------+---------------------+
|  6 |         10 | 2014-10-09 17:17:43 |
|  7 |         10 | 2014-10-10 11:38:01 |
|  8 |         10 | 2014-10-10 12:20:41 |
|  9 |         10 | 2014-10-10 12:24:19 |
| 11 |         12 | 2014-10-10 12:35:32 |
+----+------------+---------------------+
```

I want to get the latest client_profiles for each contact. That means There should be two results. I want to use subqueries to achieve this. This is the subquery I came up with:

```
SELECT `client_profiles`.* 
FROM `client_profiles` 
INNER JOIN `contacts` 
ON `contacts`.`id` = `client_profiles`.`contact_id` 
WHERE (client_profiles.id = 
(SELECT  `client_profiles`.`id` FROM `client_profiles`   ORDER BY created_at desc LIMIT 1))
```

However, this is only returning one result. It should return client_profiles with id 9 and 11.

What is wrong with my subquery?

Comment: You can't return two result sets in a query.

Comment: @LluisMartinez a contact has many client_profiles. I want to return the last client profile per contact. I figured it out before here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26045115/using-limit-with-subqueries-in-mysql/26046061#26046061, but for some reason can't get it working with this query.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you were trying to filter twice on the client_profile table, once in the JOIN/ON clause and another time in the WHERE clause.

Moving everything in the where clause looks like this:

```
SELECT `cp`.* 
FROM `contacts` 
    JOIN (
        SELECT 
            `client_profiles`.`id`,
            `client_profiles`.`contact_id`,
            `client_profiles`.`created_at`
        FROM `client_profiles`   
        ORDER BY created_at DESC 
        LIMIT 1
    ) cp ON `contacts`.`id` = `cp`.`contact_id`
```

Tell me what you think.

Comment: In your example it looks like your result set is from contacts table. I want my resultset to be from client-profiles table.

Comment: Also that is only returning 1 result, when it should be returning 2.

Comment: @DanStayntouch it cannot return 2 results because you are filtering by create date. You are explicitely asking for client_profiles with latest create date, and there's only one matching this criteria, with contact_id = 12. As you can see by yourself, there's only one client with contact_id = 12.

Comment: But I got it working before with this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26045115/using-limit-with-subqueries-in-mysql/26046061#26046061

Comment: No I am asking for client_profiles associated with contacts latest record. Becuase there are multiple contacts and each contacts has many client_profiles, there are more than one LATEST client profile per contact.

Comment: Sorry, this query does not do this. You have to review it. I'll be happy to help you further if you ask another question later!

Answer (score 0):

Should be something like maybe:

```
SELECT * 
FROM `client_profiles` 
INNER JOIN `contacts` 
ON `contacts`.`id` = `client_profiles`.`contact_id` 
GROUP BY `client_profiles`.`contact_id` 
ORDER BY created_at desc;
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/a3f21b/9

Comment: Yours is returning record of id 6, but it should be returning record of id 9 since record 9 was created last for that contact.

Answer (score 0):

You need to prequery the client profiles table grouped by each contact.. From that, re-join to the client to get the person, then again to the client profiles table based on same contact ID, but also matching the max date from the internal prequery using max( created_at )

```
SELECT
      c.id,
      c.first_name,
      c.last_name,
      IDByMaxDate.maxCreate,
      cp.id as clientProfileID
   from 
      ( select contact_id,
               MAX( created_at ) maxCreate
            from 
               client_profiles
            group by
               contact_id ) IDByMaxDate
      JOIN contacts c
         ON IDByMaxDate.contact_id = c.id
      JOIN client_profiles cp
         ON IDByMaxDate.contact_id = cp.contact_id
         AND IDByMaxDate.maxCreate = cp.created_at
```

Comment: Why so complicated? In this example, I only had to do a single subquery: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26045115/using-limit-with-subqueries-in-mysql/26046061#26046061

Comment: @DanStayntouch, although my version will work, can you show what you ARE getting as a result.